# Ubuntu 12.10 IBM SPSS Statistics throws Java error

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit

I use ubuntu version 12.10 64 bit. After I installed IBM SPSS Statistics v 21.0.0.0, I get the following java error, when trying to run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: awt (An exception was pending after running JNI_OnLoad)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1018)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:982)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:469)
at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:69)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1606)
at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1628)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at java.awt.AWTKeyStroke.<clinit>(AWTKeyStroke.java:81)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:167)
at com.spss.charteditor.resources.LabelsBundle.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at com.spss.charteditor.util.ResUtil.getBundle(Unknown Source)
at com.spss.charteditor.util.ResUtil.setLocale(Unknown Source)
at com.spss.java_client.core.common.ComponentState.setILangLocale(Unknown Source)
at com.spss.java_client.core.common.Driver.main(Unknown Source)
SPSS Client error:
Exception thrown by main.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: awt (An exception was pending after running JNI_OnLoad)
```

My current java version is:

java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss=swg21407743? Basically try installing libXp, libXmu, and libXtst libraries.